# What's wrong with or?

Tags: conditional, operators, logic

Consider

```
Clear[x];
x = 2;
x < 2.9 || x > 3.1
```

This yields

```
True
```

So, everything is o. k. ([interesting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html))
But when you replace || by or, the result becomes really interesting:

```
Clear[x];
x = 2;
x < 2.9 or x > 3.1
```

yields

```
2 < 5.8 or && 5.8 or > 3.1
```

What the heck is going on? I presume that the following is happening:

1. `or` is different from `OR` (that is, from `||`), since Mathematica is case-sensitive.
2. Thus, `or` is an other operator, perhaps a bitwise or or something like this???

I am interested in how exactly the strange value is generated. That is, if `or` is a bitwise operation, how do the left and right sides look "in bits" and how does `or` work on these bits? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The command is `Or`; your `or` is an undefined variable, as so humorously pointed out below.

Comment: Either `Or[x < 2.9, x > 3.1]` or `(x < 2.9) ~Or~ (x > 3.1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `or` is an as yet undefined symbol, the input

```
2.9 or x
```

is interpreted as the product of these three things, and evaluates to

```
5.8*or
```

in your case since you set `x=2` before.

Accordingly, if you input

```
x < 2.9 or x > 3.1
```

this evaluates to

```
2 < 5.8*or > 3.1
```

But a chain of inequalities such as `a < b > c` is always rewritten as `And[a<b,b>c]`, therefore you get

```
And[2 < 5.8*or, 5.8*or > 3.1]
```

respectively the equivalent short form using `&&`.